# vs code: incredibly laggy terminal (on mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, settings

using the latest vs code, on a new installation, with only 1 plugin (which i know not to be causing the problem, since i have repeated the whole thing with another plugin; same issue) on a mac also using the latest catalina os.

issue:

writing a couple of pages (2 or 3) to the terminal, either from the terminal itself or from within the plugin, the terminal becomes unbearably slow, scrolling up or down freezes it entirely.

i found some previous links talking about this issue, but they are with older versions of vs code, and the responses have always been "this is now fixed in  version xxx".

question:

is there some general setting in vs code that will prevent this?

or do you just have to wait for the next "updating", the next "breaking", the next "updating", etc?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this, now my terminal works faster also in Big Sur:

```
codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code\ Helper\ \(Renderer\).app
```

Comment: Can't up-vote you enough. How did I not find this sooner. Was about to fresh-install Big Sur. Kept waiting for VSC to update – but now finally solved. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a similar issue where after any input into the terminal, it would freeze completely for about a second or so and this seems to have fixed it. Thank you again!

Comment: It seems that I have to do this several times, perhaps every time Visual Studio Code updates?

Comment: Just an FYI, [the comment on this vscode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110683#issuecomment-749532841) says that this fix will no longer work. I haven't verified though.

Comment: What is this actually doing? Seems dangerous to remove a security feature